# Curves are broken while drawing path in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am using the following code to draw a path based on variable width changes on a Canvas, So far everything works fine and i can easily draw path using this code.

But the path drawn is not smooth, Especially when i draw a curved path all the lines look broken, Why does this happen? Is anything wrong in my code?

```
public class FingerPaint extends GraphicsActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) 
    {

    }

    public class MyView extends View  implements OnTouchListener
    {
        private static final float      STROKE_WIDTH = 3f;      

        private Paint                   paint = new Paint();

        private Path                    mPath = new Path();

        ArrayList<Path>                 mPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

        private Canvas                  m_CanvasView;

        private Bitmap                  m_CanvasBitmap;

        int                             variableWidthDelta = 1;

        private float                   mX, mY;

        private static final float       TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;       

        ArrayList<Point>                points = new ArrayList<Point>(64);

        public MyView(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
            this.setOnTouchListener(this);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);    
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
        {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            m_CanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            m_CanvasView = new Canvas(m_CanvasBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(m_CanvasBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);            
            m_CanvasView.drawPath(mPath, paint);    
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event)
        {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {        
                    mPath.reset();
                    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {                           
                    if (event.getPressure()>=0.00 && event.getPressure()<0.05)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 1;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure()>=0.05 && event.getPressure()<0.10)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 1;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure()>=0.10 && event.getPressure()<0.15)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 2;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure()>=0.15 && event.getPressure()<0.20)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 2;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure()>=0.20 && event.getPressure()<0.25)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 1;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure() >= 0.25 && event.getPressure()<0.30)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 1;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure() >= 0.30 && event.getPressure()<0.35)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 2;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure() >= 0.35 && event.getPressure()<0.40)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 2;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure() >= 0.40 && event.getPressure()<0.45)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 3;
                    }
                    else if (event.getPressure() >= 0.45 && event.getPressure()<0.50)
                    {
                        variableWidthDelta = 4;
                    }                  

                    paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH + variableWidthDelta);

                    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

                    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) 
                    {           
                        points.add(new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                        mPath = new Path();

                        mPath = generatePath();                                                                                                                                     
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

        class Point
        {
            public final float x;
            public final float y;
            public Point(float x, float y)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
        }

        public Path generatePath()
        {
            final float tangentScale = 0.3F;
            int pointcount = points.size();

            mPath.moveTo(points.get(0).x, points.get(0).y);
            mPath.cubicTo(
                    points.get(0).x + (points.get(1).x - points.get(0).x)*tangentScale,
                    points.get(0).y + (points.get(1).y - points.get(0).y)*tangentScale,
                    points.get(1).x - (points.get(2).x - points.get(0).x)*tangentScale,
                    points.get(1).y - (points.get(2).y - points.get(0).y)*tangentScale,
                    points.get(1).x, points.get(1).y
                    );
            for(int p=2; p<pointcount-1; p++)
            {
                mPath.cubicTo(
                        points.get(p-1).x + (points.get(p).x - points.get(p-2).x)*tangentScale,
                        points.get(p-1).y + (points.get(p).y - points.get(p-2).y)*tangentScale,
                        points.get(p).x - (points.get(p+1).x - points.get(p-1).x)*tangentScale,
                        points.get(p  ).y - (points.get(p+1).y - points.get(p-1).y)*tangentScale,
                        points.get(p).x, points.get(p).y
                        );
            }
            mPath.cubicTo(
                    points.get(pointcount-2).x + (points.get(pointcount-1).x - points.get(pointcount-3).x)*tangentScale,
                    points.get(pointcount-2).y + (points.get(pointcount-1).y - points.get(pointcount-3).y)*tangentScale,
                    points.get(pointcount-1).x - (points.get(pointcount-1).x - points.get(pointcount-2).x)*tangentScale,
                    points.get(pointcount-1).y - (points.get(pointcount-1).y - points.get(pointcount-2).y)*tangentScale,
                    points.get(pointcount-1).x, points.get(pointcount-1).y
                    );

            return mPath;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onTouch` event is not fired fast enough, so if you draw curves fast enough you will see this happening.

You can improve the point resolution by getting all recorded points between this onTouch event and the last one. Use [`event.getHistorySize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getHistorySize%28%29) to get the amount of available points, and get their positions with [`event.getHistoricalX(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getHistoricalX%28int,%20int%29) and [`event.getHistoricalY(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getHistoricalY%28int,%20int%29).

If you still have problems, you would probably have to implement some sort of interpolation of the points.
Here is a simple example using [`cubicTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#cubicTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) to get a smooth path:
`points` is an array of all points that are to be drawn.
`pointcount` is the amount of points

```
//This code is untested
public Path generatePath(){
Path path = new Path();
if( points.size() < 3 ) return path;
final float tangentScale = 0.3;

path.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
path.cubicTo(
    points[0].x + (points[1].x - points[0].x)*tangentScale,
    points[0].y + (points[1].y - points[0].y)*tangentScale,
    points[1].x - (points[2].x - points[0].x)*tangentScale,
    points[1].y - (points[2].y - points[0].y)*tangentScale,
    points[1].x, points[1].y
    );
for(int p=2; p<pointcount-1; p++){
    path.cubicTo(
        points[p-1].x + (points[p].x - points[p-2].x)*tangentScale,
        points[p-1].y + (points[p].y - points[p-2].y)*tangentScale,
        points[p  ].x - (points[p+1].x - points[p-1].x)*tangentScale,
        points[p  ].y - (points[p+1].y - points[p-1].y)*tangentScale,
        points[p].x, points[p].y
        );
}
path.cubicTo(
    points[pointcount-2].x + (points[pointcount-1].x - points[pointcount-3].x)*tangentScale,
    points[pointcount-2].y + (points[pointcount-1].y - points[pointcount-3].y)*tangentScale,
    points[pointcount-1].x - (points[pointcount-1].x - points[pointcount-2].x)*tangentScale,
    points[pointcount-1].y - (points[pointcount-1].y - points[pointcount-2].y)*tangentScale,
    points[pointcount-1].x, points[pointcount-1].y
    );
return path;
}
```

Adapting this for your specific case:
(You will have to modify the above method to use `.get()` instead of array accessors, since I am using a list here)

```
//A class for holding x and y values:
class Point{
    public final float x;
    public final float y;
    public Point(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

//In your View:
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Points>(64);

//In the onTouch-method if the tolerance is ok:
points.add(new Point(event.getX(), event.GetY());
mPath = generatePath();
```

The above will generate a rounded path that you can draw. Note that it uses all points, so they will all be redrawn every time (you might have to clear the canvas to avoid some artiefacts). You might want to move the `generatePath`-call to when you lift the finger, so you get a faster, but jagged preview path while drawing.

Comment: I do some changes as you mention, and yes there come some smoothness in the line, but still not perfect, Can u please look at my edited code if i miss something.

Comment: Have u able to see my changes. Actually i am stuck on this issue for last week, but able to get any correct solution.

Comment: @Anshuman Try to implement som sort of interpolation between the values, I am not 100% sure about your avaraging the x/historicalX values. 
If this is not enough, Try incorporating hardware acceleration if you are using an API level over 10. Also try to optimize your onTouch code to improve speed. You might also consider using a second thread for processing events.

Comment: Frankly speaking what you suggest is really bouncing my head. Is it possible for you to provide me some sample code / Examples for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but can u let me know on which part of my code i used this logic, and what actually the points array and what need to be store in points array.

Comment: @Anshuman I added a small example of how you can interpolate the curvature of the path with `cubicTo`. I have not tested it, but it should work. You will have to adapt it to your specific case.

Comment: @Java Yeh I Understand what you are saying. Actually i am new on using this, So not able to get how to used this logic in my code, I am totally confused, Can u give me some more hint of using this in my code, if you have a time.

Comment: Thanks...i will try and let you know.

Comment: @Java Edited my answer, but here once i tried to draw something the app crash and show arrayIndexOutofbound Exception, can you please check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43427/discussion-between-jave-and-anshuman)

Comment: @Java Yeh its working, but now the line that i draw is not changed based on pressure value, means initially in my code the path user draw is based on variable width path,but now whats happening is, If i used light pressure the path start drawing with thin line and then if i give more pressure while drawing the same path, the thin path take the same width as get by applying more pressure.